# How to rearrange dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple problem but being very new to R, I cannot seem to figure it out. I have a dataframe of the following structure:

```
         V1    V2   V3   V4
STATE    0     0    1    1
Period   1     2    1    2
avg_FTE  40    35   42   35
```

I would like to rearrange this to the following:

```
STATE      0     1 
Period 1   40    42
Period 2   35    35
```

I expect the answer is quite straightforward but for some reason this has tripped me up.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(reshape)
Input = (
  'V1    V2   V3   V4
STATE    0     0    1    1
Period   1     2    1    2
avg_FTE  40    35   42   35 ')
df = read.table(textConnection(Input), header = T)
df <- as.data.frame(t(df))
t(dcast(df, STATE~Period, fill=0))
      [,1] [,2]
STATE    0    1
1       40   42
2       35   35
```

We can fix the output a bit:

```
colnames(res) <- res[1,]
res <- res[-1,]

   0  1
1 40 42
2 35 35
```

Answer (score 0):

additional solution

```
library(tidiverse)
df %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Period, names_from = STATE, values_from = avg_FTE)
```